# setPreferredSize() dosent work in my JButton

Tags: java, resize, jbutton

Im creating a Tic Tac Toe game out of Java and i seem to be stucj in one problem i cant get out of :( . I cant rezize my button. I tried both tried both setSize and setPreferredSize but dosent seem to work:

Here is the setPreferedSize pic:
[image]

And Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.xml.XMLLib.Factory;



public class TicTacToe {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    JButton row1col1;
    JButton row1col2;
    JButton row1col3;
    JButton row2col1;
    JButton row2col2;
    JButton row2col3;
    JButton row3col1;
    JButton row3col2;
    JButton row3col3;   


    public TicTacToe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        frame = new JFrame("Fds");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        row1col1 = new JButton();
        row1col1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        contentPane.add(row1col1);

        row1col2 = new JButton();
        row1col2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        contentPane.add(row1col2);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }


    private static void runGUI() {
         JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
         TicTacToe greeting = new TicTacToe();
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
         run from an event-dispatching thread */
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         runGUI();
         }
         });


         }


}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BoxLayout respects the maximum size of the component.

In your case the maximum size is less than the preferred size.

However, the solution is NOT to play with the preferred/maximum sizes.

Instead you can use:

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
```

to control the size of your button, then normal layout management can be done as the preferred size will be calculated correctly.

Comment: So how do i fix that exactly? Sorry for bothering you sir.

Comment: @ewrwr, I was just in the middle of providing a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Camickr states, BoxLayout respects maximal size, but having said that, why use BoxLayout? Instead I suggest:

- If you want to create a grid of JButtons, use GridLayout as it excels at creating grids.
- It somewhat respects preferred sizes as long as you pack your GUI, and all the components are the same size,
- But having said that, don't set the size. For tic tac toe, set the JLabel's font to something large, or use JLabels with ImageIcons that are large, so that your GUI sets its own size correctly.
- You should be using an array or 2D array of JButtons for ease of coding.

For example please check out my code here: [Java: Drawing using Graphics outside the class which draws the main canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646179/522444) which uses programmer created ImageIcons and creates this GUI:

[image]

Or my code in this answer: [How to wait for a MouseListener mouse press?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33880467/522444) which uses Font sizing to create this GUI:

[image]